# Identify the tables that don't have any rows?

Tags: sql, hana

Is there a SQL statement to identify which tables don't have any data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can query system view [M_TABLES](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/20c7689a75191014ad52c1beb40ce2d2.html):

```
SELECT * 
FROM M_TABLES 
WHERE RECORD_COUNT = 0
```

Please be aware, that the content of `M_TABLES` is subject to the authorization concept.